# Using recent selenium server (2.41) cannot open url in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, selenium

I have been running unit tests using Selenium Server 2.32 and Firefox 24.4 (on CentOS 5)  -- just updated Firefox, and moved to Selenium 2.41, and now Selenium won't open a URL. I assume something has changed in either Firefox or Selenium that I need to adapt to, but can't figure out what.

I created as clean a test program as I could, which follows. It works (opens google.com in a Firefox window) using Selenium 2.32, but not in Selenium 2.41. As best I can tell from looking at the Selenium output it is getting a 404 error, but no idea way.

Any help gratefully appreciated !

Test Case in php:

```
$seleniumUrl  = "http://mydomain.com:4444/wd/hub";
$desired_capabilities = array('browserName' => 'firefox');
$results = mycurl(
      $seleniumUrl,
      'POST',
      '/session',
      array('desiredCapabilities' => $desired_capabilities),
      array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true));

$seleniumUrl = $results['info']['url'];

$goToUrl = "http://google.com";
mycurl($seleniumUrl, 'POST', '/url', array('url' => $goToUrl));
```

Here is the source to mycurl function:

```
function mycurl(
    $seleniumUrl,
    $http_method,
    $command,
    $params = null,
    $extra_opts = array()) {

    if ($params && is_array($params) && $http_method !== 'POST') {
      throw new Exception(sprintf(
        'The http method called for %s is %s but it has to be POST' .
        ' if you want to pass the JSON params %s',
        $command,
        $http_method,
        json_encode($params)));
    }

    $url = sprintf('%s%s', $seleniumUrl, $command);
    if ($params && (is_int($params) || is_string($params))) {
        $url .= '/' . $params;
    }

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt(
       $curl,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
       array(
         'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
         'Accept: application/json'));

    if ($http_method === 'POST') {
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      if ($params && is_array($params)) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
      }
    } else if ($http_method == 'DELETE') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    }
    foreach ($extra_opts as $option => $value) {
         curl_setopt($curl, $option, $value);
    }
    $raw_results = trim(curl_exec($curl));
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

    if ($error = curl_error($curl)) {
       $msg = sprintf(
             'Curl error thrown for http %s to %s',
             $http_method,
             $url);
       if ($params && is_array($params)) {
           $msg .= sprintf(' with params: %s', json_encode($params));
       }
       throw new Exception($msg . "\n\n" . $error);
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    $results = json_decode($raw_results, true);

    $value = null;
    if (is_array($results) && array_key_exists('value', $results)) {
       $value = $results['value'];
    }

    $message = null;
    if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('message', $value)) {
       $message = $value['message'];
     }

     return array('value' => $value, 'info' => $info);
  }
```

Comment: I am not seeing any actual Selenium code in your above example other than you named your variable 'seleniumUrl'.  So, is this a PHP question or a Selenium question?  Quite a bit of noise is generated by all the extra stuff you are including here.  Can you reduce it to a Hello World style example?

Comment: I am sending two commands to the standalone Selenium server: /session,  and /url, via curl. The latter is supposed to open the url (google.com, in this case) in a firefox browser. However, in the latest version of Selenium server, the browser window opens, but doesn't go to the url. The Selenium log is showing a 404 error. What I am trying to figure out is why this works with the older version of Selenium server (2.32) but not 2.41.

Comment: Not sure how to reduce this any more. The curl() code itself is probably not relevant, but it seems possible, if unlikely, that the issue is there, since the code to send commands to Selenium is itself so simple.

Comment: It sounds like you could figure out the problem by comparing a Wireshark trace of your Curl method vs. selenium events from a typical Java/Python coded method.